# get value of custom variable with PHP when using PayPal Instant Payment Notification

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to implement PayPal IPN with PHP on my server. I found the code from Paypal on [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php). My understanding is that i put `PaypalIPN.php` and my version of `example_usage.php` on server and specify the url of my version of `example_usage.php` to PayPal.

example_usage.php looks like this:

```
<?php require('PaypalIPN.php');

use PaypalIPN;
$ipn = new PayPalIPN();
// Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
$ipn->useSandbox();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {
    /*
     * Process IPN
     * A list of variables is available here:
     * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
     */

***** This is where I should get the value of custom and store it in DB or whatever *****
** getPOSTdata() used here **

}
// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly.
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

I will be sending custom variables to paypal in the following way:

```
<a id="a-submit" href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&custom=customdata&hosted_button_id=someID">Pay with PayPal</a>
```

Paypal should return it under the custom variable. How can I access it? Small subquestion. Is this really it? It looks extremely easy and I am worried that I am missing something.

EDIT: I edited `PaypalIPN.php` with the following function:

```
private $postData = "";

  public function getPOSTdata(){
        return $postData;
    }

**IN verifyIPN()**
 $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$postData=$raw_post_data;
```

I use it in the following way:

```
$lastname = $ipn->getPOSTdata();
```

The problem that I am facing is that `$lastname` is an empty string. That can't be true, since I know PayPal must have send me something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By looking at PaypalIPN.php, I would modify it so I can get access to "$myPost" variable defined in "verifyIPN". That actually contains all data passed from PayPal, included you custom data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a method to access the *$myPost* array inside *PaypalPN.php*

PaypalIPN.php Lines 6 - 8

```
private $use_sandbox = false;

private $use_local_certs = true;
```

Change to the following:

```
private $use_sandbox = false;
public  $pubMyPost;
private $use_local_certs = true;
```

Then further down...

PaypalIPN.php Lines 75 - 79:

```
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
    }

    // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
```

Change to:

```
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
    }
    this.pubMyPost = $myPost; // set the public var
    // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
```

Then inside example_usage.php

```
$ipn->useSandbox();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {
    // Now you can access all the public var containing your key=value pairs from the post.
    $myPost = $ipn->pubMyPost;
}
```

Comment: Also, it is probably best to make a *getPostFields* method for that PaypalIPN class but for the sake of brevity I just created a public property that can be easily accessed.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using $_POST["valueIwant"] in if (verifyIPN){} clause. Not sure why I wanted to complicate things in the frst place.